# How to store 30000 plus characters in a particular text field, which datatype should be use for it? sql*plus

Tags: oracle, datatypes, sqlplus

Here, I have a problem in which I want to store 30000 plus characters (paragraphs) in an individual field instance.

Moreover, I tried the CLOB datatype for a column, but when I am crossing the characters storing up to 2900, it gives me an error:

> ORA-00972: the identifier is too long.

So which datatype is best/suitable to store maximum characters or I would say store 2 or 3 paragraphs in a particular field in a single row.

As a newbie, your meaningful response will be appreciable.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

Your **column name** is too long.  The error you mentioned has nothing to do with the length of the data.

Comment: Yes, I alter too my column name but same error occurs ....

Comment: @Faisal.softech ...and the `CLOB` data type can store over 2 billion characters in it, so your 30,000 character data definitely fits.

Comment: @Vérace, Oracle 12c and above supports identifiers with up to 128 bytes in length, so ... your comment (about 30 characters) is just partially valid. We don't know which Oracle database version the OP uses, they never specified it. Maybe identifier's length exceeds 30 characters (that's probably *it* and I believe you're actually right), but - theoretically, it can be longer than 128 characters (OK, *bytes*) as well.

Comment: Wow - just reclicked on the link I posted - it's now showing that from release 12, it's 128. I'll just delete my comment! Thanks for the heads up!